What does 女意識してるmean in romantic context?
お前みたいに明らかに女意識してるやつモテルわけじゃないだろ
The character is bragging that a girl was pointing at him and probably has a crush on him,but his friend tell him this.
What does "女意識" exactly mean? I've seen it used before in romantic context but I don't understand? Aware of girls?

There is no such a word as 女意識. を has been omitted after 女, and 意識する is a plain transitive suru-verb.

お前みたいに明らかに女(を)意識して(い)るやつ
someone like you who's obviously conscious about women

